# OAuth Auth Dialog for our site does not display 'Access my basic Information'

Tags: facebook, oauth

Having a bit of a problem here (well OAuth is working for us, but the auth dialog does not display as is advertised on the technical specs). We make a call to the OAuth dialog, but then the dialog only asks the user to log in. The thing is, after getting the token back, we do have access to that user's basic information. Am I missing something here? Has something changed?

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too!  I guess what you're observing is the 'enhanced' authorization dialog.  You can get this display the traditional/expected dialog by changing your app's setting:
goto developers.facebook.com -> apps -> settings -> advanced -> Migrations : Enhanced Auth Dialog, set to Disabled and then save.

Good luck!